# Pytorch maximum inner product without materializing intermediate

Tags: pytorch

I'd like to do the equivalent of

```
# X.shape = (batch, M, D)
# Y.shape = (N, D)
Z = torch.max(torch.bmm(X, Y.T), dim=2)
```

while only paying memory cost `(batch, M)` by not materializing an intermediate of size `(batch, M, N)` (because, as you may have guessed, I run out of GPU ram).  I can do this manually by slicing the bmm and accumulating the max, but that's alot of cuda kernel calls, so it kinda sucks.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: I'm not aware of any linear algebra tricks that would allow for this. As you've stated you could slice it. Something like `Z=X@Y[0]; for i in range(1,N): Z=Z.maximum(X@Y[i])`. You'll almost certainly be losing some efficiency though.

Comment: Yeah I'm more hoping for "here's a kernel somebody wrote that does the slicing on the gpu side for you".

Comment: If you do the multiplication in submatrices, you can get good cache-locality hence better performance than the scan-line computing (did you mean this by "slicing"?). If 1 kernel call is 100 microseconds (python + cuda api) latency, then you can hide that latency by having multiple multiplications in-flight. There must be an asynchonous cuda kernel launch option in torch. If not, then you will lose performance.